# Python/Selenium: How to set "value" for input when it is not listed in page source?

Tags: python, selenium, input

This is the html on the site:

```
<input name="PROJECT_CODE" type="text" size="15">
```

But in fact, if you inspect element, you can edit-in an input value, and the site updates, filling in the blank, i.e.:

```
<input name="PROJECT_CODE" type="text" size="15" value="VALUE">
```

So when finding by xpath, I am having trouble changing (let alone locating) input value. This is what I currently have, guessing that value="".

```
projcode = raw_input("what's the projcode? \n")
projcode_retrieved = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value=""]")
projcode_retrieved.send_keys(projcode)
```

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. Could you explain *why* you want to do this? Preferably add a [MCVE].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is how HTML works. Do not use the `@value` attribute when locating `input`s. Instead you can use something that does not change, like:

```
driver.find_element_by_name("PROJECT_CODE")
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also try with using xpath for element,

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("*//input[@name='PROJECT_CODE']");
```